# Truecrypt rescue disk not working on boot partion to recover password?

Tags: truecrypt

I installed some Windows XP updates last night. My boot partition is fully encrypted with Truecrypt. When I tried to boot it up tonight it just keeps saying incorrect password!

I tried to restore key header in rescue disk but still says incorrect password so tried the boot header loader which said it restored but I still same issue after boot.

I can not even get into the boot manager to format it and start again as it states no bootable partition found.

Please let me know what do as I am panicking so much!

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: I need it to boot I don't know where to turn Google isn't helping

Comment: Do you have any backups?

Comment: I have the rescue disk but it's not working can I just install xp over the encrypted partion and overwrite it?

Comment: Is it possible that your `Caps Lock` key is pressed?

Comment: No caps lock double checked tried a different keyboard to. Think the stupid xp updates have done something. No idea how to get this laptop back

Comment: You can indeed install Windows XP over the encrypted partition.  This of course means that you lose any data on the encrypted partition.  If your recovery cd does not work you might be out of luck.  This is the reason backing up your data is always important.

Comment: What exactly do you want to do know? Format that partition and overwrite it with new,  clean XP or do you want to recover your data first?

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried removing the drive and mounting it (through Truecrypt) on another machine?

Just use the...

`System -> Mount Without Pre-Boot Authentication`

...option and enter the password for the encrypted volume and it should mount like a regular Truecrypt volume. This would allow you to verify that the data is accessible.

Alternatively, you can use the Rescue Disk to try to decrypt the laptop drive. From the Rescue Disk, select...

`Repair Options -> Permanently decrypt system partition/drive`

...and enter your password. This will take some time to complete and will leave the drive decrypted. This would at least let you get in to fix things. You could then re-encrypt the drive at a later date.

If it will not boot after being decrypted, you may need to use the Rescue Disk to restore the original system boot loader. You can do this in the Rescue Disk with...

`Repair Options > Restore original system loader`

...However this should ONLY be done as a last resort and only after the drive is decrypted.

If none of this works, your best bet is to reinstall. This is, after all, the intention of full disk encryption: to protect the contained data from access.

Good Luck!

Comment: Will this just overwrite the data?

Comment: The first option just lets you mount the encrypted drive on another computer (if you have the password). The second returns to drive to an unencrypted state. The third option should only be used after completely decrypting. If the first two don't work, you'll have to reinstall and wipe out everything.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't remember the password and the header is good (which is what the rescue disk repaired if it was broken), formatting is your only choice.

Pop in your install disc and format the disk and start over.

Comment: Thanks password is definitely correct though it's the one I have written down